# Can we block Search Engine crawlers from indexing system URLs

Tags: magento2, search, nginx

Can we block access for Search Engine Crawlers to all system URLs.

I know we can do this by adding rules to robots.txt. 
But can we also achieve this on the server level (Nginx)

Thnx, and Kind Regards

Comment: Define "system URLs"?

Comment: system URLs like 

*/catalogsearch/
*/catalogsearch/advanced/
*/catalog/product/view/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can by doing this tag on the header

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
```